# Rails & Devise: Make Variable Available in Devise View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, devise

I can't seem to find this anywhere... I'm trying to add a dashboard to one of my devise screens (registrations/edit), but I need to make some variables available.  How do I do this without rewriting all of the devise controller logic?

Comment: Did you read the "Configuring Controllers" part of https://github.com/plataformatec/devise ?

Comment: Yes I did, but like I said, I don't want to have to completely rewrite my controller, I just want to add a variable.

Comment: You don't have to. Let me write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the devise controller for that purpose, and call the parent method.

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def edit
    super
    @your_var = 'something'
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: Expected `/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb to define Devise::RegistrationsController`.  I tried adding `Users::RegistrationsController` to the registrations controller, upon which it gives me `uninitialized constant Users`.  Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I created a folder for devise in controllers, and apparently it didn't like that.  Moved it to the top level and the error went away, but my variable still isn't available... it isn't throwing an error, it's just showing up as blank

Comment: Did you update your routes.rb file according to the documentation ? When you create a directory into your controllers directory, every controller in it will be part of the module which has the same name as the new directory.

Comment: I just moved it up a level.  My routes file is as such: http://cl.ly/image/340L031R2L3F

Comment: Well there is no error.  I just left your controller example so it had `"@your_var=something"`, but it doesn't show anything when I try to call it.  It's as if I never set it.  debug @your_var shows nothing but an ellipsis... in fact, I don't even think it's calling my registrations_controller.rb file at all -- if I change things in the file to make it completely wrong it's still not throwing an error.

Comment: Ok, I found it. Don't put your controllers into the Devise module. It can be tricky for the autoloader.

Comment: I don't know what you mean... where am I putting my controllers into the devise model?

Comment: That was the most vague, least helpful thing to say.  A link would be helpful, or even telling me what docs your talking about.  As far as devise goes, I've read and re-read the documentation about controllers, but there's very little.  If you're talking about taking out the controllers definitions in my routes.rb file, I've changed it to this: http://cl.ly/image/1g0g0D3I1i0Z , but to no avail.